# Add Values to Lead Activity in CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

Im trying to add a value to the field `RegardingObjectId` on activity for Leads.

I have tried doing this;

```
 myAct.RegardingObjectId = activityParties;
```

But i get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference'

I also tried:

```
 myAct.RegardingObjectId = recordRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

But i get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntityReference'

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`RegardingObjectId` is a lookup to another record and should be populated along the lines of:

```
myAct.RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference("new_entityname", new Guid("your record id"));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,"new_entityname" would the name of the new activity and "your record id" would recordRow.cells[0]?

Comment: "new_entityname" is the name the entity, e.g. task, incident, account. "your record id" is the id of the record, e.g. a GUID. How could I possibly know what is in `recordRow.cells[0]`?

Comment: ok , thanks for that, how could i link it to the column name in the db then?

Comment: If you dont already had the GUID, but you know the name of the record you could search for the record in the database based on its name.